# How to get the battery temperature details in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidevice

I am getting battery status and others .

```
UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[myDevice setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float batLeft = [myDevice batteryLevel];
int i=[myDevice batteryState];

int batinfo=(batLeft*100);

NSLog(@"Battry Level is :%d and Battery Status is :%d",batinfo,i);

switch (i)
{
    case UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged:
    {

        break;
    }
    case UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging:
    {

        break;
    }
    case UIDeviceBatteryStateFull:
    {

        break;
    }
    default:
    {

        break;
    }
}
```

Now i am trying to get the temperature details is it possible to get the battery temperature from device .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain Battery temperature in IOS programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287831/obtain-battery-temperature-in-ios-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother I gone through the answer for your question and which indicates that you can get and generally it shows the following states

```
Battery design capacity
Battery current raw capacity (in mAh)
Battery cycle count
Current battery temperature
Current battery voltage
Current battery discharge rate (device power consumption), in mA
```

Also following shows the results of battery

```
{
AdapterDetails =     {
    Amperage = 1000;
    Description = "usb host";
    FamilyCode = "-536854528";
    PMUConfiguration = 1000;
    Watts = 5;
};
AdapterInfo = 16384;
Amperage = 1000;
AppleRawCurrentCapacity = 1279;
AppleRawMaxCapacity = 1275;
AtCriticalLevel = 0;
AtWarnLevel = 0;
BatteryData =     {
    BatterySerialNumber = REDACTED;
    ChemID = 355;
    CycleCount = 524;
    DesignCapacity = 1420;
    Flags = 640;
    FullAvailableCapacity = 1325;
    ManufactureDate = REDACTED;
    MaxCapacity = 1273;
    MfgData = REDACTED;
    QmaxCell0 = 1350;
    StateOfCharge = 100;
    Voltage = 4194;
};
BatteryInstalled = 1;
BatteryKey = "0003-default";
BootBBCapacity = 52;
BootCapacityEstimate = 2;
BootVoltage = 3518;
CFBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.driver.AppleD1815PMU";
ChargerConfiguration = 990;
CurrentCapacity = 1275;
CycleCount = 524;
DesignCapacity = 1420;
ExternalChargeCapable = 1;
ExternalConnected = 1;
FullyCharged = 1;
IOClass = AppleD1815PMUPowerSource;
IOFunctionParent64000000 = <>;
IOGeneralInterest = "IOCommand is not serializable";
IOInterruptControllers =     (
    IOInterruptController34000000,
    IOInterruptController34000000,
    IOInterruptController34000000,
    IOInterruptController34000000
);
IOInterruptSpecifiers =     (
    <03000000>,
    <26000000>,
    <04000000>,
    <24000000>
);
IOMatchCategory = AppleD1815PMUPowerSource;
IOPowerManagement =     {
    CurrentPowerState = 2;
    DevicePowerState = 2;
    MaxPowerState = 2;
};
IOProbeScore = 0;
IOProviderClass = AppleD1815PMU;
InstantAmperage = 0;
IsCharging = 0;
Location = 0;
Manufacturer = A;
MaxCapacity = 1275;
Model = "0003-A";
Serial = REDACTED;
Temperature = 2590;
TimeRemaining = 0;
UpdateTime = 1461830702;
Voltage = 4182;
"battery-data" =     {
    "0003-default" = <...>;
    "0004-default" = <...>;
    "0005-default" = <...};
"built-in" = 1;
}
```

Above things are from [UIDeviceListener](https://github.com/eldoogy/UIDeviceListener)

I run with sample code I got below temparature

[image]

[image]

in EEPowerInformation.m class I put the breakpoint and check that.It is called and brings all information about battery.

```
- (void) listenerDataUpdated: (NSNotification *) notification
{
  latestPowerDictionary = notification.userInfo;
  NSLog(@"The latest Power Dictionary is - %@",latestPowerDictionary);
  NSLog(@"The battery Temperature is - %@",[latestPowerDictionary objectForKey:@"Temperature"]);
  if (self.delegate != nil)
    [self.delegate powerInformationUpdated: self];
}
```

The Printed Statements are

```
The latest Power Dictionary is - {
AdapterDetails =     {
    Amperage = 1000;
    Description = "usb host";
    FamilyCode = "-536854528";
    PMUConfiguration = 970;
    Watts = 5;
};
AdapterInfo = 16384;
Amperage = 1000;
AppleChargeRateLimitIndex = 0;
AppleRawBrickIDVoltages =     (
            (
        39,
        420
    )
);
AppleRawCurrentCapacity = 1084;
AppleRawExternalConnected = 1;
AppleRawMaxCapacity = 1221;
AtCriticalLevel = 0;
AtWarnLevel = 0;
BatteryInstalled = 1;
BatteryKey = "0003-default";
BootBBCapacity = 673;
BootCapacityEstimate = 29;
BootVoltage = 3810;
CFBundleIdentifier = "com.apple.driver.AppleARMPlatform";
ChargerConfiguration = 900;
CurrentCapacity = 1222;
CycleCount = 343;
DesignCapacity = 1430;
ExternalChargeCapable = 1;
ExternalConnected = 1;
FullyCharged = 0;
IOClass = AppleARMPMUCharger;
IOFunctionParent5E000000 = <>;
IOGeneralInterest = "IOCommand is not serializable";
IOMatchCategory = IODefaultMatchCategory;
IONameMatch = charger;
IONameMatched = charger;
IOPowerManagement =     {
    CapabilityFlags = 32832;
    CurrentPowerState = 2;
    DevicePowerState = 2;
    MaxPowerState = 2;
};
IOProbeScore = 1000;
IOProviderClass = IOService;
InstantAmperage = 198;
IsCharging = 1;
Location = 0;
Manufacturer = A;
MaxCapacity = 1300;
Model = "0003-A";
Temperature = 3120;
TimeRemaining = 67;
UpdateTime = 1470665642;
Voltage = 4188;
"built-in" = 1;
}
```

Finally the Printed result of battery Temperature is

```
The battery Temperature is - 3120
```

Comment: user thanks for the answer but is it accurate temperature or assumption @user3182143

Comment: Not assumption brother it is  actual output from UIDeviceListener

Comment: bro i actually added your code and it giving me zero because i am running it  on simulator ,i gave upvote once i verified it on device then i give correct for the answer

Comment: Run with device brother

Comment: today not possible bro device is not here ,tomorrow i will check mostly i will   try to check it by today

Comment: Once you get let me know brother

Comment: but its not working in device also bro device temperature and all giving me zero values only

Comment: Did you check well?

Comment: Did you follow the 'How does it work?' instruction carefully?

Comment: Yes bro I followed

Comment: Brother success I tried UIDevice Listener Github sample code for you with iPhone device I got temparature.

Comment: but bro it doesn't work on iOS 10 ,they mentioned it so my app it is not suitable right

Comment: Now I run with IOS 9 and above also it works fine.I got the solution what you ask yesterday.

Comment: bro are you there @user3182143

Comment: Now it is working but if user moves to iOS 10 means the problem will occurs ,so please update the answer for  ios10 its not work like that

Comment: I don't have iOS 10.Your question is very valuable.I got the solution according to your question with source.

Comment: Even if you googled now your question comes first now.My answer is very very useful for everyone.

Comment: Are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120478/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-user3182143).

Answer (score 1):

**That is not possible and there is no public API to find .** but I found the some answers in here May be it helps you , [see once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024247/getting-battery-health-information-on-ios). But some private API you can get this details.

> **[sample app](https://github.com/ethan605/ios-battery-stat)** you cannot use this if you deploy your app on the Apple Store, but it can be useful when deploying to TestFlight

Answer (score 1):

if you don't need temperature number then it is useful to use **ThermalState** api

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsprocessinfothermalstate?language=objc